# EJB on MQ - get queue depth

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, ejb-3.1

I have an SLSB with connection factory and queue injected:

```
@Stateless
public class MQTestBean {
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/MQQCF")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/testQueue")
    private Queue testQueue;
}
```

I would like to be able to inquire the queue for the following attributes:

- current depth
- open input count
- open output count

Please keep in mind, that the channel's user I am using has only access to DSP, GET, PUT, INQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but there is no way to do it. At least using the WMQ JMS client jar. 
You can calculate a q depth indirectly by counting-while-browsing, and that's about it.

For input/output count you are gonna need MQ api (MQI/PCF whatever suits you).

edit:
added url: [MQ Classes for Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/ja10120_.htm)

Comment: I just found out the same thing so sadly this answer is acceptable :)